# cordova - Arguments to path.resolve must be strings on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: git, cordova, visual-studio-2015, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm develop a cordova application on Visual Studio 2015, I have several plugins, including the PushPlugin from phonegap. I added this plugin from git URI. The issue is when I compile the project, an error "Arguments to path.resolve must be strings" is generated and the process fail.

This is my output: http://pastebin.com/RvjQjQKG

In the config.xml, my code for the plugins is this:

```
<vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.3.0" />
<vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.6.0" />
<vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" version="0.2.15" />
<vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" version="0.3.0" />
<vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" version="1.0.0" />
<vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.statusbar" version="0.1.10" />
<vs:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin" version="2.5.0" src="https://github.com/phonegap-build/pushplugin.git" />
```

Please, help me to identify what is the problem, I have many days with this issue and I can't resolve it.

Thank you in advance.

Regards from Mexico

Comment: Have you followed: *In your Visual Studio project add reference to the Newtonsoft.Json.dll as well - it is needed for serialization and deserialization of the objects.

Also you need to enable the "ID_CAP_PUSH_NOTIFICATION" capability in Properties->WMAppManifest.xml of your project.*

Comment: Also remove the tag [tag:git]. It has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, thee 2.5.0 version of PushPlugin have many mistakes (https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/610); I've put the Git URI adding the `#2.4.0` in the end of this and then I could add the plugin without issues. Thanks for your responses.